# Ubuntu 18.04 won't boot after changing login screen background

Tags: boot, gnome

I tried to change my login screen background via modifying /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css file mistakes were made. So my boot process stuck at "started gnome display manager... and deal with any system changes" line.

Any chances to restore?

Comment: Have you tried switching to a text terminal (ctrl+alt+f4 etc) and correcting your mistake(s)? then either rebooting or restarting your gui/dm?

Comment: To be fair i'm a Linux noob. I've been trying single user/multi user emergency/recovery modes for days. Somehow I was able to run vi commands and revert the change i made (editing css file line as its original state) but didn't work out. I cannot open the tty terminal while last booting commands flow, everything is tagged as [OK] but it won't open after waiting more than an hour. And i couldn't understand exactly how to restart gui/dm or how to get there.

Comment: If you just changed something related to gnome or a gui theme I cannot see how text terminals were disabled unless you also disabled them. If you used commands to make changes, the commands will show in your `history`, and if you're like me as for edits - I leave plenty of comments esp. if I'm testing/experimenting so boo-boos are easy to reverse. Changes to packages can be viewed in /var/log/apt/history* log files.  If it's a user config you messed up you can reset to config by creating a new user & copying from there, but system configs may mean re-install is easiest unless you have backups.

Comment: If you go the re-install route, I would suggest using 'something else' where you can select your existing partitions and select 'no-format'.  This will cause system directories to be erased, re-install occurs, and added programs (if from Ubuntu repos) to be re-added to your system thus fixing system directory (ie. global) issues - but this will not fix any user-config issues as it won't touch user directories. Backup of course data that is valued before you do it, but for user-level changes my prior comment already indicated how I'd fix those (ie. copy configs from another created/good user)

Comment: Thank you sir, i'm gonna re-install and give it a try. I just changed "resource: org/..." Line to "file:". How did it can mess up with entire interface, kinda frustrating, i can't get it. And yeah, i'll do daily backup once i made it through.